# Simple networking, now that UNet is deprecated

Tags: unity, unity-networking

I'm prototyping a two-player typing game in Unity. I don't have any experience making multiplayer games, so I'm not sure how to best approach the netcode.

For this game all I think I really need is an API for sending messages to and from a server - the two clients only care about what the other one is typing, and there isn't any gameplay that's even remotely related to physics. Looking into UNet, it seems like the parts based on synchronizing game objects do more than my game needs, but the [messaging stuff](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActionsAndCommunication.html) from the HLAPI seems like a good fit. That said, this *is* a real time game, so low latency is ultimately more important than any API style considerations.

The wrench, however, is that Unity is deprecating UNet without shipping any replacements. I'd start working with HLAPI, but I don't want to have to replace all of the networking code down the line or even have to shut down the game when Unity's servers go down, if that's what will happen after using HLAPI.

So as a beginner to multiplayer development, with relatively low API requirements, where do I go when Unity multiplayer is in flux? Should I learn the DOTS-Netcode mentioned in [this recent blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/06/13/navigating-unitys-multiplayer-netcode-transition/)? Should I go with a third party solution like Photon? Or will the HLAPI be sufficient, even post-deprecation?

Comment: I dabbled with MLAPI which kind of a port of unet with lots of addons to give 'Mid Level' access. There was another one I used that I forget the name of that is similar to MLAPI and can be downloaded free from asset store. Although  I downlaoded them from Github i believe (sorry it was a while ago)